# Issues with WSO2 API Manager 3.2.0 high availability endpoints

Tags: wso2-api-manager

We have configured the high availability for API end points as mentioned here https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/learn/design-api/endpoints/high-availability-for-endpoints/#configuring-load-balancing-endpoints

In Load balance and Failover Configurations we have chosen the "EndpointType" as "Load Balanced". We could see the requests are routed to these load balanced end points successfully. However when we stop any one of the end-point node, 2 requests are still routed to the stopped node before the remaining requests are successfully routed to the active node. This is happening again and again when we receive new requests. The particular failed end-point is not marked as inactive or down

The error response are
{"fault":{"code":101503,"type":"Status report","message":"Runtime Error","description":"Error connecting to the back end"}}

The entries from carbon logs are attached below

TID: [-1234] [] [2022-12-14 09:51:23,307]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.throttling.ThrottleHandler} - Error while getting throttling information for resource and http verb
TID: [-1] [] [2022-12-14 09:51:23,308]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ConnectCallback} - Connection refused or failed for : /100.66.2.32:7010
TID: [-1234] [] [2022-12-14 09:51:23,309]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.EndpointContext} - Endpoint : NewMCMInboundChannel-RESTAPIService--vv2_APIproductionEndpoint_1 with address http://100.66.2.32:7010/mcm-provider will be marked SUSPENDED as it failed
TID: [-1234] [] [2022-12-14 09:51:23,309]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.EndpointContext} - Suspending endpoint : NewMCMInboundChannel-RESTAPIService--vv2_APIproductionEndpoint_1 with address http://100.66.2.32:7010/mcm-provider - current suspend duration is : 30000ms - Next retry after : Wed Dec 14 09:51:53 UTC 2022
TID: [-1234] [] [2022-12-14 09:51:23,310]  WARN {org.apache.synapse.endpoints.LoadbalanceEndpoint} - Endpoint [NewMCMInboundChannel-RESTAPIService--vv2_APIproductionEndpoint] Detect a Failure in a child endpoint : Endpoint [NewMCMInboundChannel-RESTAPIService--vv2_APIproductionEndpoint_1]
TID: [-1234] [] [2022-12-14 09:51:23,310]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} - {api:admin--NewMCMInboundChannel-RESTAPIService:vv2} STATUS = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 101503, ERROR_MESSAGE = Error connecting to the back end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here what you are experiencing is the default behavior of the endpoint suspension. Any endpoint created with API Manager can be in 3 states.

1. Active
2. Timeout
3. Suspended

In your configuration, since you have configured two endpoints in a load-balanced manner, initially both endpoints are in the active state. Both endpoints share the load. Once the endpoint 2 is stopped, the next request routed to the endpoint failed with an error code and that has put the endpoint from active to suspended state.

There are three configurations you can set in such suspended situation.

1. Error code (The error code which puts the endpoint from active to suspended state)
2. Initial suspension duration.
3. Maximum duration
4. Progression Factor

In the default configurations, initial suspension duration is set to 30 seconds. This means, server will remove the suspended state of the endpoint after 30 seconds from the endpoint failure and will put it back to the active state. That's why you can observe that endpoint is getting active from time to time. This is expected as the server tries to determine whether the endpoint is active or not.

You can increase this suspension time with the configurations and suspension time is calculated considering the other 3 configurations.

> Endpoint suspension time = Min(current suspension duration *
> progressionFactor, maximumDuration)

With each failed attempt, the progression factor will increase the suspension duration until the maximum time. This will reset once the endpoint has served at least one successful request.

You can configure all the in the publisher UI, endpoints section as below.

[image]

More information on endpoint suspension can be found in here [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYDUX.jpg).

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYDUX.jpg) - https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Endpoint+Error+Handling

Comment: Hi Lakshitha, Thanks for the detailed info. Assume that we need to check and suspend the endpoint every 30 minutes in case of a connection time out. Can we use below settings.

Initial Duration (ms): 1800000 (30 mins)
Max Duration (ms): 1800000 (30 mins)
Factor 1.

Also to check the timeout every 15sec and mark two consecutive failure as suspended
Retries Before Suspension = 2
Retry Delay = 15000 (15sec)

Comment: yeah. you can. Setting the initial and max duration to 30mins will guarantees that the gateway will remove the endpoint from the suspended state after 30mins.

Comment: Hi Lakshitha, the requests are still failing with above settings. We are getting "Failover endpoint : NewMCMInboundChannel-RESTAPIService--vv2_APIproductionEndpoint - no ready child endpoints" or "Error connecting to the back end" message.
In log file we can clearly see it is suspended for 30 minutes but still the requests are failing. Suspending endpoint : NewMCMInboundChannel-RESTAPIService--vv2_APIproductionEndpoint_0 with address http://100.66.213.31:7010/mcm-provider - current suspend duration is : 1800000ms - Next retry after : Mon Jan 09 13:01:36 UTC 2023